# Using spec/merge with spec/multi-spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Can I use `s/merge` with `s/multi-spec`?  For example

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(s/def :field/common (s/keys :req-un [:field/type :field/name]
                             :opt-un [:field/default]))

(s/def :field/max-length int?)

(defmulti field-type :type)
(defmethod field-type :character [_]
  (s/merge :field/common
           (s/keys :req-un [:field/max-length])))
(defmethod field-type :foreign-key [_]
  (s/merge :field/common
           (s/keys :req-un [:field/references])))
(defmethod field-type :int [_]
  ;; ??? what to do here? - I only want the common keys
  :field/common)
(defmethod field-type :boolean [_]
  ;; ??? what to do here? - I only want the common keys
  :field/common)

(s/def ::field (s/multi-spec field-type :field/type))
```

What would I put for the `:int` and `:boolean` methods? I only need the common fields.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that this is what you want, but I would think you'd use the normal multimethod inheritance approach.

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(s/def :field/common (s/keys :req-un [:field/type :field/name]
                             :opt-un [:field/default]))

(s/def :field/max-length int?)

(defmulti field-type :type)
(defmethod field-type :character [_]
  (s/merge :field/common
           (s/keys :req-un [:field/max-length])))
(defmethod field-type :foreign-key [_]
  (s/merge :field/common
           (s/keys :req-un [:field/references])))

(defmethod field-type :field/common [_]
  :field/common)

(derive :int :field/common)
(derive :boolean :field/common)

(s/def ::field (s/multi-spec field-type :field/type))
```

Comment: If it works, I like it.  Thanks, I'll give it a try!